# Jquery extend() merges anonymous objects but doesn't merge instances of my classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend, object-oriented-analysis

This works fine:

```
.extend(true, {}, { name: "john doe", age: 20, address: {street:"aaa", number:"bbb"} }, { gender: "M", address: {} })
```

But when **address** is a class then the second address overrides the first one instead of merging them.

```
function Address(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

$.extend(true, {}, { name: "john doe", age: 20, address: new Address({street:"aaa", number:"bbb"}) }, { gender: "M", address: new Address({}) })
```

Is that a bug or an expected behavior of jQuery? How do I merge two instances of a class?

Comment: I consider any weirdness you get with `$.extend` due to dealing with things that aren't plain objects as expected. It simply isn't intended for that use-case.

Comment: Not to mention... Is it even possible to "merge" two separate instances of a class? I guess if you break it down to just the properties you could, but that cold result in weirdness depending on how the properties are constructed and how it affects other parts of said class.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a merge function for your class, which might be as simple as hitting `$.extend` inside the class with plain objects.

Comment: Note that there aren't any classes here, just constructors and constructed objects. Classes are something that may come in ES6.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Even in ES6 I think classes eventually boil down to the same prototypical pattern we all learned to love.

Comment: @elclanrs yes, still prototypical, but with some more overcomplications. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the other answer, you could try to convert it to a plain object, although I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but it should work:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name + ' says hello!';
};

var toPlainObject = function(x) {
  var obj = Object.create(null);
  for (var i in x) obj[i] = x[i];
  return obj;
};

// false
// Person {name: 'John', say: function}
$.isPlainObject(new Person('John'));
// true
// Object {name: 'John', say: function}
$.isPlainObject(toPlainObject(new Person('John')));
```

Comment: When I look at that, I'm tempted to add `toPlainObject` as a method of `Person`, but then at that point it isn't as reusable.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.extend` always copies from right to left. The second overrides the first, and the third overrides the second. Therefore, the property value of `address` from the third of course overrides the property value of the second. It doesn't merge deeper than that because the property value of `address` fails the `jQuery.isPlainObject()` test.

```
function Address(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

console.log( jQuery.isPlainObject(new Address()) ); // false
```

if `Address` instead returned a plain object, this wouldn't happen.

```
function Address(data) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.data = data;
    return obj;
}

console.log( jQuery.isPlainObject(Address()) ); // false
```

Comment: `$.extend` source for reference: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7e8a91c205723f11cd00c8834f348a649ab15926/src/core.js#L162